# Where to find info on the "service call" shell command?

Tags: shell

Using `adb shell` or a terminal emulator on the device, entering this will clear all notifications (requires `su`)

```
service call notification 1
```

This will send an sms (doesn't require `su`)

```
service call isms 5 s16 "PhoneNumber" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "BodyText"
```

Where can I learn more about `service call`? I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719898/service-call-isms-with-adb-shell-android-sdk) on StackOverflow and appreciate the answer's breakdown as to what everything means. But where can I find info on what method `notification 2` might be trying to call?

Running `service call` was incomplete and printed this usage:

```
Usage: service [-h|-?]
       service list
       service check SERVICE
       service call SERVICE CODE [i32 INT | s16 STR] ...
Options:
   i32: Write the integer INT into the send parcel.
   s16: Write the UTF-16 string STR into the send parcel.
```

I ran `service list` and it came back with 78 services for my device including `isms` and `notification` and for most services will print what seems to be a namespace (`com.android.internal.telephony.ISms` for `isms` and `android.app.INotificationManager` for `notification`). How can I use this information to find out what I can do with each of these services?

Comment: also asked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/20227326/7552

Comment: Exactly. And even answered here: [Where to find description of all “/system/bin/service” calls?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/34625/16575)