# How to check IMSI/ICCID on MIUI10?

Tags: sim-card, miui, redmi, miui-10

Is there any way to view IMSI and ICCID numbers of my SIM-cards? I didn't find such menu neither in About-Status nor anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are APIs available which apps (like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.harrygonzalez.simcardinfo)) use to read SIM information. Looking for CLI solution (refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14817021/9165920), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29357619/9165920) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203636/218526)), we can get IMSI and ICCID with following commands respectively (up to Android 9):

```
~$ service call iphonesubinfo 7
```

```
~$ service call iphonesubinfo 10
```

<sup>* Codes depend on order of methods defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IPhoneSubInfo.aidl), which may differ on different Android versions.</sup>
<sup>* For dual SIM device use code `8` and `11` instead and append `i32 2` to command to get second SIM information.</sup>

Pass the output through following pipes to convert hexadecimal output to a good looking string:

```
... | grep -oE '[0-9a-f]{8} ' | while read hex; do echo -ne "\u${hex:4:4}\u${hex:0:4}"; done; echo
```

Terminal emulator apps usually don't have permission `READ_PHONE_STATE` (though you can [grant manually](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217522/218526) with root) which is required by both functions. So commands need to be executed from `adb shell`.

Codes `7`/`8` correspond to [getSubscriberId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSubscriberId()) and `10`/`11` to [getSimSerialNumber](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getSimSerialNumber()). However both methods have been [removed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids) for normal apps usage in Android 10. Only system apps with `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` will be able to get this information. `iphonesubinfo` service can't be dumped with `dumpsys` either. So root is the only solution on Android 10+.

RIL may also log the operator/SIM related information to `logcat` when SIM state changes. With root access it's possible to read telephony database (the component of application framework which interfaces RIL) and also RIL database itself (which interfaces modem). On my Qualcomm device RILD stores information to `/data/vendor/radio/qcril.db` including ICCID and MCC/MNC.

```
~# sqlite3 -line /data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db 'select icc_id,card_id,carrier_name,display_name,mcc,mnc from siminfo'
```

```
~# sqlite3 /data/vendor/radio/qcril.db 'select ICCID from qcril_manual_prov_table'
```

As of Android 9 IMSI is also stored in `/data/system/netpolicy.xml` to set mobile data limits for MNOs separately.

```
~# grep -o 'subscriberId=[^ ]*' /data/system/netpolicy.xml
```

---

**RELATED:**

- [How to get 2nd IMEI number using adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219105/218526)

Comment: Thanks, finally tried this exceptional answer, it works!

Comment: One more question: I have 2-SIM phone, but putting the `i32 2` after 8 or 11 doesn't do the job, it gives me the same numbers as w/o this append. Is my command correct?

Comment: `service call iphonesubinfo 11 i32 2 | grep -oE '[0-9a-f]{8} ' | while read hex; do echo -ne "\u${hex:4:4}\u${hex:0:4}"; done; echo`

Comment: @Suncatcher you may try `i32 1` or `i32 0`. For all Android 9 sub-releases order of `getSubscriberIdForSubscriber` and `getIccSerialNumberForSubscriber` methods is 8 and 11. If it doesn't work then possibly Xiaomi changed the source code. You have to do hit and trial.

Comment: Well, for IMSI `8 i32 3` works, and for ICCID `11 i32 3` gives `8938001120308300159F` instead of `8938001120308300159`. Probably we should correct regex for extraction of ICCID but I have no idea how. I've never dealt with hex-extract in regex

Comment: @Suncatcher in raw output I get `00000000` in last row. Do you get `00000046` (which becomes `F`)? You can ignore last character using `head` or `tail`.

Comment: `in raw output I get 00000000 in last row` [the same](https://i.imgur.com/sNqN3pA.png). Interesting why it is so different for 2nd SIM. Tried to append `| head -c -1` and `| sed -e 's/;$//'` after `echo` but that didn't work. How to cut the last sign correctly?

Comment: @Suncatcher `00000000` itself turns to two Unicode null characters. So you need to do `head -c -3`.

Comment: it says `head: -c < 0 (see "head --help")` seems to be the wrong syntax

Comment: @Suncatcher use `busybox head`. Android's `toybox` is limited.