# Can Sensors Off (developer options) be controlled via ADB?

Tags: adb, developer-options, sensors

Can Sensors Off (developer options) introduced in Android 10 be controlled via ADB?

[image: Sensors Off tile | System UI]

Haven't got it from AOSP sources yet: [Sensors Off | Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensors-off#:%7E:text=Android%2010%20provides%20a%20developer,the%20sensors%20in%20their%20device.)

Comment: Try calling [`setSensorPrivacy`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/libs/sensorprivacy/aidl/android/hardware/ISensorPrivacyManager.aidl#29). Read [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217971/218526) how to do this.

Comment: Ohh, I barely got there, @irfan-latif.

I used the service list command to get the existing list. Then when I call it with the command service call sensor_privacy 4 i32 1, it outputs the parcel result, as in the link below.

It seems, there is also something that must be given a value for it to run. However, I don't know how.

Photos:
- ![service list](https://photos.app.goo.gl/G4evtLrtvAEWDEfH9).
- ![service call sensor_privacy 4 i32 1](https://photos.app.goo.gl/tnnwJ49hNxw7Nx8m6).

Btw, specifically my device is running Android 12L, and I'm new to this. My B Markdown.

Comment: You are calling the wrong method. For [Android 12](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/tags/android-12.1.0_r1/libs/sensorprivacy/aidl/android/hardware/ISensorPrivacyManager.aidl#37) the code should be 7, not 4.

Comment: One number left below.. 

It's on 8th method. Now, it works! 

Photos: [service call sensor_privacy 8](https://photos.app.goo.gl/8CXGSF6GJqX7SgqA9). 

Take your point by answering. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks to @irfan-latif for providing the right answer to this question in the comments column. But apparently, this will be allowed. So, I will help complete the answer.

On Android 10:

```
service call sensor_privacy 4 i32 1

service call sensor_privacy 4 i32 0
```

On Android 11:

```
service call sensor_privacy 4 i32 1

service call sensor_privacy 4 i32 0
```

On Android 12:

```
service call sensor_privacy 8 i32 1

service call sensor_privacy 8 i32 0
```

On Android 12L:

```
service call sensor_privacy 8 i32 1

service call sensor_privacy 8 i32 0
```

On Android 13:

```
service call sensor_privacy 9 i32 1

service call sensor_privacy 9 i32 0
```

Else, the above command does not produce anything, you can search for ISensorPrivacyManager Interface in [Android Code Search](https://cs.android.com/android) according to the revised version of your Android device[2] (Hint: the number on the back is the revision number.). Then, change the sequence number of the Method in which setSensorPrivacy() resides.

[2]: getprop | grep ro.vendor_dlkm.build.id

Comment: The specific error I get is `Result: Parcel(00000000    '....')` Oneplus 5T, LineageOS 18.1 / Android 11. Both `service call sensor_privacy 4 i32 1` and `[...] 0` of course.

Comment: Yeah.. indeed the output of the both commands is `Result: Parcel(00000000 '....')`, and check the Sensors Off icon on the notification bar.

Else, you need to check the ISensorPrivacyManager Interface on your phone's Android version/revision to Android Code Search, or you can contact the developer of the ROM concerned for help. Because, this command is the basis of AOSP.